# Handling the Gray scale images in the List Box control for Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing Windows Phone 8.  I'm binding list of images on List Box, and trying to apply Gray scale.

When image list exceeds more than 15, image list get collapsed, few images come in Gray and few images come in color and images get repeated.

Please advice me to achieve it corretly.

Comment: i need to display more items in the List view. Actually it is containing in the Pivot Control.

Comment: First I created the Pivot Control. In the First Pivot it has contained some list items. now I am showing the list items in the Second Pivot using List Box


<ListBox x:Name="lstSalesToCome">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <salesUC:CustomSalesToCome></salesUC:CustomSalesToCome>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

In the List Box I used the Custom controls to display Images. Now I am handling the Gray Scale Conversion in the Image Opened Property.

Comment: private void imgSaleProduct_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 WriteableBitmap ProductImage = new WriteableBitmap(imgSaleProduct, null);
 imgSaleProduct.Source = ChangeGrayScale(ProductImage);            
 }